PlatformException (PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)) Better Player
Hello I'm using better player for hls video. It's working in android without any problem but in ios always getting error like PlatformException (PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)). And url is not contain .m3u8 how can I solve it. This is my code
  Future<void> initPlayer() async {
try {
  controller = BetterPlayerController(
    BetterPlayerConfiguration(),
    betterPlayerDataSource: BetterPlayerDataSource.network(
      widget.url,
      headers: data,
      videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.hls,
      notificationConfiguration: BetterPlayerNotificationConfiguration(),
    ),
  );
  setState(() {});
} catch (e) {
  log('Error initializing BetterPlayer: $e', name: 'BetterPlayer Init');
}

}
